# Confused with probability in R

Tags: r, probability

I'm completely new to R, and I was given a problem that has a code that says "a = runif(1) < .2"

Does that mean the probability of a occurring is 0.2 or 0.8?

Comment: there is 0.2 probability of a being TRUE

Answer (score 1):

`runif(1)` will give you 1 sample from a uniform distribution, between 0 and 1:

```
runif(1)
[1] 0.04113232
```

That is then compared against `0.2` and will return a boolean i.e. "is my sampled value less than 0.2?"

```
runif(1) < .2
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: For clarity, the number in the first code block (`0.0411`) is a different number from the number (that we do not see) generated in the second code block. One should not infer that `0.0411 < 0.2` would return `FALSE`. (A technicality, but since the OP was unclear on the expression as a whole, I thought it might be beneficial.)

Comment: Setting the seed before each time a random function is excuted is one way to address this. `set.seed(2021); runif(1); # 0.4512674`

Answer (score 1):

You can see it in action by running the random uniform function 10,000 times and viewing the results in a table:

```
set.seed(2021)
table(runif(1:10000) < 0.2)
```

> ```
> FALSE  TRUE 
>  8044  1956
> ```

20% True